# Linux Capabilities with User Namespaces

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, namespace, capabilities

I'm confused about how file capabilities work with regards to user namespaces. As I understand it, if a file has a capability, then any threads/process executing the file can attain the capability.

On my ping binary, I have the CAP_NET_RAW capability set, and there is no setuid.

```
# CAP_NET_RAW is set
→ getcap `which ping`                                               
/bin/ping = cap_net_raw+ep

# There is no setuid
→ ls -l `which ping`                                                 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 64424 Mar  9  2017 /bin/ping

# ping works...
→ ping -c 1 google.com                                               
PING google.com (172.217.6.46) 56(84) bytes of data.                                                  
64 bytes from sfo03s08-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.6.46): icmp_seq=1 
ttl=54 time=11.9 ms                

--- google.com ping statistics ---                 
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms                                           
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 11.973/11.973/11.973/0.000 ms
```

So why is it that I cannot ping from my user namespace?

```
→ ping google.com      
ping: socket: Operation not permitted 

→ capsh --print        
Current: = ...cap_net_raw...+ep                                                         
Bounding set =...cap_net_raw...                                                       
Securebits: 00/0x0/1'b0                            
secure-noroot: no (unlocked)                      
secure-no-suid-fixup: no (unlocked)               
secure-keep-caps: no (unlocked)                   
uid=0(root)                                        
gid=0(root)                                        

→ getcap `which ping`  
/bin/ping = cap_net_raw+ep
```

Comment: Does not a _process_ (context) have capabilities, not a file?! Sub-processes inherit it.

Comment: @Ned64 You have probably figured it all out now, but for posterity -- there is the notion of "file capabilities", see the man-pages for `capabilities`. Indeed, Linux may associate capabilities with file system objects using extended attributes, but you are also correct in that it is _processes_ that are associated with capabilities -- although files can thus be said to be as well.

Answer (score 4):

> The child process created by clone(2) with the CLONE_NEWUSER flag starts out with a complete set of capabilities in the new user namespace. Likewise, a process that creates a new user namespace using unshare(2) or joins an existing user namespace using setns(2) gains a full set of capabilities in that namespace. **On the other hand, that process has no capabilities in the parent** (in the case of clone(2)) or previous (in the case of unshare(2) and setns(2)) user namespace, even if the new namespace is created or joined by the root user (i.e., a process with user ID 0 in the root namespace).

...

> When a non-user-namespace is created, it is owned by the user namespace in which the creating process was a member at the time of the creation of the namespace. Actions on the non-user-namespace require capabilities in the corresponding user namespace.

-- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/user_namespaces.7.html

You can't get raw net access to network interfaces which you don't own!

```
$ unshare -r
# ping -c1 127.0.0.1
ping: socket: Operation not permitted
```

Compare:

```
$ unshare -rn
# ping -c1 127.0.0.1
connect: Network is unreachable
# ip link set dev lo up    # apparently the `lo` interface is pre-created.
# ping -c1 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms

--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.048/0.048/0.048/0.000 ms
```