# Ping not working in a new C container

Tags: permissions, ping, network-namespaces, capabilities, userns

I've been working on writing my own Linux container from scratch in C. I've borrowed code from several places and put up a basic version with **namespaces** & **cgroups**.

Basically, I **clone** a new process with all the **CLONE_NEW*** flags to create new namespaces for the **clone'ed** process.

I also set up UID mapping by inserting **0 0 1000** into the **uid_map** and **gid_map** files. I want to ensure that the *root* inside the container is mapped to the *root* outside.

For the filesystem, I am using a base image of **stretch** created with **debootstrap**.

Now, I am trying to set up the network connectivity from inside the container. I used [this](https://gist.github.com/dpino/6c0dca1742093346461e11aa8f608a99) script to setup the interface inside the container. This script creates a new network-namespace of its own. I edited it slightly to mount the net-namespace of the created process onto the newly created net-namespace via the script.

```
mount --bind /proc/$PID/ns/net /var/run/netns/demo
```

I can just get into the new network namespace as follows:

```
ip netns exec ${NS} /bin/bash --rcfile <(echo "PS1=\"${NS}> \"")
```

and successfully ping outside.

But from the bash shell when I get inside the clone'ed process by default I am unable to PING. I get the error:

```
ping: socket: Operation not permitted
```

I've tried setting up capabilities: **cap_net_raw** and **cap_net_admin**

I would like some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to work from a more complete specification.  However from careful reading of the script and your description, I conclude you are entering a network namespace (using the script) first, and entering a user namespace afterwards.

The netns is owned by the initial userns, not your child userns.  To do `ping`, you need cap_net_raw in the userns that owns the netns.  I think.

There is a similar answer here, which provides links to reference documentation: [Linux Capabilities with User Namespaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423095/linux-capabilities-with-user-namespaces/430249#430249)

(I think `ping` can also work without privilege if you have access to ICMP sockets.  But at least on my Fedora 29, this does not seem to be used.  Unprivileged `cp "$(which ping)" && ping localhost` shows the same `socket: Operation not permitted`.  Not sure why it has not been adopted).

Comment: This indeed guided me towards the right answer. So in my code, I had cloned with all the flags and *unshare(CLONE_NEWUSER)* later since I had to set up things like mount points. When I moved the CLONE_NEWNET also to the unshare call after the clone() it worked as expected.